# I want to insert data in to SQLite Database that encrypted with javax.crypto.cipher

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using that packages

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
```

this is Function that get Data from table_1 and Store in table_2

```
 public void encrypDatabase() throws Exception {
            String queGetData = "select ans, img from table_1";
        String  ans;
        int img;
    Cursor c = vDatabase.rawQuery(queGetData, new String[] {});

    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {  ans = getEncryptedString(c.getString(0));
                img = c.getInt(1);

                String queinsertData = "insert into table_2 values(" + ans + "', "+ img + ")";

                eDatabase.execSQL(queinsertData);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

This is function for ciphering that work 100%

```
public String getEncryptedString(String s) throws Exception {

    try {

        kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128);
        skey = kgen.generateKey();

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getString(cipher.doFinal(getBytes(s)));
}
```

// getString() it function that return byte[] to String

I am unable to insert data in table_2
how to solve this problem

else any way to direct get Encrypted database that can decrypted by using javax.cripto.cipher

Hear String data is 'UTF-8' like "दीन-हीन अति मलिन मति"

this is Hindi Text

Comment: what do you mean you can't insert? are there any errors? also note you have missed a single quote `'` in insert statement `values(" + ans + "'` it should be `values('" + ans + "'` it's better to use ContentValue to do insert()

Comment: if I insert data without encryption then it work completely  but after encryption that give me error like        `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "M": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into rto values(4, '?@??QH?9ø0??', '0d?w??|????'M')`

Comment: ignore rto it just table_2

Comment: maybe because some special characters like **ø** the method that returns String from encrypted data `getString()` should use Base64#encode, it generate valid string with no special characters, and use Base64#decode before trying to decrypt data

Comment: Base64#encode work complete but Base64#decode not working

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: I pass string through Base64#decode it return null